# Pygame - designing the code

Tags: python, pygame

My apologies for the poor title. I have experience with how game's code is written with C# (XNA) or java (LibGDX), but I have recently started using python and pygame specifically and I have trouble figuring out how to design the code. This is how I thought it would make to do:

game.py file:

```
import pygame
import entities

width = 400
height = 300
# Set up the window size
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((width, height), 0, 32) 
player = entities.Player(width / 2, height / 2)  # The player

#main game loop is here...
```

entities.py file:

```
import pygame
import game

class Player:
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        # Texture for the player
        self.texture = pygame.image.load('player.png')

    def draw(self):
        """ Draws the player """
        game.screen.blit(self.texture, (self.position.x, self.position.y))

#class Enemy: ...
```

However this code give me errors. I think the problem is that I am importing `entities.py` in the `game.py` and then I import `game.py` in the `entities.py`.

How would I go about to properly design this in python ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend to use what pygame already offer.

Take a look at the classes [`Sprite`](http://pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Sprite) and [`Group`](http://pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Group) (and their more complex subclasses).

So your player class could look like:

```
class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):

    def __init__(self, x, y):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        # Texture for the player
        self.image = pygame.image.load('player.png')
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(topleft=(x, y))

    # no need for a draw function
    # the sprite class will handle this
    # just make sure you store the coordinates of 
    # your entity in self.rect

    def update(self, some_game_state):
        pass # do something with some_game_state
```

Then, in your game, you would put all of your entities in one (or more) group(s), and just call `draw` and `update` on that group(s).

```
entities = pygame.sprite.Group(player) # add other sprite here, too

# main loop
while True:
    ...

    # pass the game state to all entities
    # how you design this is up to you
    # (pass multiple values, pass a single instace of the game class,
    # create a class that encapsulates the state necesseray for the entities etc.)
    entites.update(some_game_state) 

    # pass the main surface to the draw function
    entities.draw(screen) 

    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You should pass the variables into the relevant classes, rather than making them globals and importing them. So, one possible solution would be to make `screen` an attribute of Player:

```
class Player:
    def __init__(self, x, y, screen):
        self.screen = screen
        ...

    def draw(self):
        """ Draws the player """
        self.screen.blit(...)
```

Now, there is no need to import `game` in entities.py, and you can instantiate the player there like this:

```
player = entities.Player(width / 2, height / 2, screen)
```

There are probably other ways to do this, but this should give you the idea.

Comment: It doesn't make sense for a Player or entity to have a `screen` attribute. That should be an attribute that would go inside a `static class Game` in C# or java. Also, I would have to access many variables, if not all the variables from my `game.py` file. This will result in having many parameters on all of my functions later on, which will be very confusing. Any other ideas ?

Comment: I don't see why it needs to be a static attribute; it's a piece of data that the Player needs to reference, so it's perfectly sensible for it to be an instance attribute. Anyway, if you don't want to do that, you could just pass it as an argument to `draw`.

Comment: Well this seems a bit better. Would it make sense to wrap up the code I have inside `game.py` inside a `game` class and pass that as a parameter when I need more than just 1 variable ? Or this seems just worse ?